# How to create triple nested objects in Rails with multiple-directional associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, simple-form, nested-forms

An article called [Triple nested Forms in Rails](https://medium.com/@mindovermiles262/triple-nested-forms-in-rails-dedbcccb5799) presents a good description of creating a form for saving three nested objects. The example given is of creating a `Show` that `has_many Seasons`, and each `Season` has_many `Episodes`. Also, `Episode --> belongs_to --> Season --> belongs_to --> Show`. 
Shows are created like this:

```rb
def new
@show = Show.new
@show.seasons.build.episodes.build
end
```

The form looks like this:

```
<%= form.fields_for :seasons do |s| %>
    <%= s.label :number %>
    <%= s.number_field :number %>    <%= s.fields_for :episodes do |e| %>
      <%= e.label :title %>
      <%= e.text_field :title %>
    <% end %> 
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This seems straightforward because all the associations run in one direction. I'm trying to do something that's similar, but more complicated. I have a `Parent` model where each `Parent` has multiple `Children` and each `Child` is enrolled in a `School`. After specifying that `Children` is the plural of `Child`, the association would have to be like this:

```
Parent has_many Children, accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
Child belongs_to Parent, belongs_to School, accepts_nested_attributes_for :school
School has_many Children, accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
```

Graphically, it would look like this:

```
Parent <-- belongs_to <-- Child --> belongs_to --> School
```

Each Parent is also associated with a User, like this:

```
User has_many :parents
```

The data on Parents, Children, and Schools is entered in the following form (generated using the Simple Form gem), where the schools are entered as a dropdown selector populated from the schools table:

```
@schools = School.all

<%= simple_form_for (@parent) do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :name, label: 'name' %>
     <%= f.simple_fields_for :children, @children do |child_form| %>
         <%= child_form.input :name, label: "Child Name" %>
         <%= child_form.simple_fields_for :school, @school do |school %>
             <%= school.collection_select :id, @schools, :id, :name, {}, {} %>
            <% end %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I set up the `new` controller method to create a `Parent` having three `Children` enrolled in an existing `School`. Then I tried to associate the `Children` with a `School` that already exists in the `schools` table with id = 1.

```rb
def new
   @parent = Parent.new
   # creating 3 children
   @children = Array.new(3) {@parent.children.build}
   @school = School.find(1)
   @school.children.build
end
```

This throws an error

```
Couldn't find School with ID=1 for Child with ID=
```

The error is located in the first line of the create method, which looks like this:

```rb
def create
    @parent = Parent.new(parent_params.merge(:user => current_user))
    if @parent.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :new, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def parent_params
    params.require(:parent).permit(:name, :child_attributes => [:id, :name, age, :school_attributes => [:id, :name]])
end
```

Since the error text states `"Child with ID= "`, the error must be thrown before ids for new `Children` are assigned. Why can a `School` with ID=1 not be found when it exists in the `schools` table? Or, does this mean that a `School` record has not been properly associated with an instance of `Child` before an attempt is made to save that instance? If so, how can I fix the association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common missconceptions/misstakes with nested attributes is to think that you need it to do simple association assignment. You don't. You just need to pass an id to the `assocation_name_id=` setter.

If fact using nested attributes won't even do what you want at all. It won't create an assocation from an existing record when you do `child.school_attributes = [{ id: 1 }]` rather it will attempt to create a new record or update an existing school record.

You would only need to accept nested attributes for school if the user is creating a school at the same time. And in that case its probally a better idea to use Ajax rather than stuffing everything into one mega action.

```
<%= simple_form_for (@parent) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'name' %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :children, @children do |child_form| %>
    <%= child_form.input :name, label: "Child Name" %>
    <%= child_form.associaton :school, 
        collection: @schools, label_method: :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

```
def parent_params
  params.require(:parent).permit( :name, 
    child_attributes: [:id, :name, :age, :school_id]]
  )
end
```

Comment: Thank you max! This was very helpful. I changed the form and the parent_params as you suggested. I also changed the `create` method to create a new Parent, get their children (`@children = @parent.children`), and then iterate over the children and associate a school with each child, where the id of the school is taken from params: `@children.each_with_index do |child, index| index = index.to_s; selected_school = School.find(params[:parent][:children_attributes][index][:school_id]); child.update(school: selected_school)`